# Agregar librería JS externa a un proyecto en react

Tags: javascript, html5, reactjs

Este es el problema, yo tengo un pequeño proyecto solo en `html` y `js` y quisiera pasarlo a React, convertir el `html` a sintaxis `jsx` no fue un problema, la cuestión es poder utilizar las librerías JS que dependía el proyecto al nuevo proyecto en React. Aquí se los presento, es una ruleta:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Ruleta</title>
    <script src="Winwheel.min.js"></script><!--Estas son las librerias-->
    <script src="TweenMax.min.js"></script><!--Estas son las librerias-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="Girar" onclick="miRuleta.startAnimation();" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <canvas id="canvas" height="400" width="400"></canvas>

    <script>
      var miRuleta = new Winwheel({
        numSegments: 5, // Número de segmentos
        outerRadius: 170, // Radio externo
        segments: [
          // Datos de los segmentos
          { fillStyle: "#f1c40f", text: "CSharp" },
          { fillStyle: "#2ecc71", text: "JavaScript" },
          { fillStyle: "#e67e22", text: "Python" },
          { fillStyle: "#e74c3c", text: "Php" },
          { fillStyle: "#8e44ad", text: "Go" }
        ],
        animation: {
          type: "spinToStop", // Giro y alto
          duration: 5, // Duración de giro
          callbackFinished: "Mensaje()", // Función para mostrar mensaje
          callbackAfter: "dibujarIndicador()" // Funciona de pintar indicador
        }
      });

      // Funciones complementarias
      dibujarIndicador();
      function Mensaje() {
        var SegmentoSeleccionado = miRuleta.getIndicatedSegment();
        alert("Elemento seleccionado:" + SegmentoSeleccionado.text + "!");
        miRuleta.stopAnimation(false);
        miRuleta.rotationAngle = 0;
        miRuleta.draw();
        dibujarIndicador();
      }
      function dibujarIndicador() {
        var ctx = miRuleta.ctx;
        ctx.strokeStyle = "navy";
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(170, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(230, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(200, 40);
        ctx.lineTo(171, 0);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fill();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Las librerías las saqué de aquí](https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B1D53uMGH6xzSFo4MndwdjJJQ2s)

El objetivo de esto es poder convertirlo en un componente más y reutilizarlo en otros proyectos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma mas adecuada sería usando [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/import)

```
import Winwheel from 'la/ruta/a/Winwheel.min.js';
import TweenMax from 'la/ruta/a/TweenMax.min.js'; 

var miRuleta = new Winwheel()// El resto del código
```

y en los respectivos archivos *Winwheel.min.js* y *TweenMax.min.js* usando [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/export):

```
export default class Winwheel{
    //El código...
}
```

Si exportas varias clases en un mismo archivo tienes que hacerlo un poco distínto, también hay varias sintaxis posibles que están detaladas en la documentación.